# Angular 2 binding: TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Consider the below code, or see this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/mwPHfz?p=info.

**Master**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {DetailComponent} from "./detail.component";
import {User} from "./user";
import {MOCKUSERS} from "./mock-users";

@Component({
    directives: [DetailComponent],
    selector: "master",
    template: `
        <h2>Master</h2>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="#user of users" (click)="selectUser(user)">
                    {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <detail [user]="selectedUser"></detail>
        </div>
    `
})
export class MasterComponent {
    users: User[] = MOCKUSERS;
    selectedUser: User;

    selectUser(user: User) {
        this.selectedUser = user;
    }
}
```

**Detail**

```
import {Component, Input} from "angular2/core";
import {User} from "./user";

@Component({
    selector: "detail",
    template: `
        <h2>Detail</h2>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class DetailComponent {
    @Input()
    user: User;
}
```

**User**

```
export class User {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
}
```

When you click on a name in the list (master) the form (detail) should be updated. The first name and last name properties should appear in the firstName and lastName inputs respectively.

However, when you look in the developer tools, you can see the following error when loading the app:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_user0 is undefined in [user.firstName in DetailComponent@4:27]

So somehow the binding to user doesn't seem to be accepted. Can anyone tell why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an undefined object (before selecting a user) to DetailComponent. You should only render the DetailComponent if there is a selectedUser.

```
<div *ngIf="selectedUser">
  <detail [user]="selectedUser"></detail>
</div>
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FIPCRb?p=preview). In index.html, I had to replace the imported angular js file from angular.min.js to angular.dev.js to fix an unrelated issue on your plunker.

Comment: I had already tried the *ngIf but the main issue for me was indeed the angular file that needed to change. In another project I switched from beta 6 to beta 8 and things started working there as well.

Comment: @Aetherix there are still some open issues on the minified bundle, check [#6380](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6380)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-group users-list">
    <li class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let user of users"
        (click)="selectUser(user)"
        [class.active]="user === activeUser">
        {{ user.name }} ({{ user.username }})
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you should initilize selectedUser parametes.

```
export class MasterComponent {
    users: User[] = MOCKUSERS;
    selectedUser: User = null;

    selectUser(user: User) {
        this.selectedUser = user;
    }
}


<div>
  <detail [user]="selectedUser"></detail>
</div>



@Component({
    selector: "detail",
    template: `
        <h2>Detail</h2>
        <div *ngIf="user !== null">
            <div>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})

export class DetailComponent {
    @Input() user: User = null;
}
```